# speech recognition not taking input

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio, google-speech-api

I am using the following code, but it is not taking any inputs. It just prints listening and nothing happens, does not take input, and the program also does not terminates.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r1=sr.Recognizer()
r2=sr.Recognizer()
r3=sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Listening')
    audio = r3.listen(source)
    print(r2.recognize_google(audio))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with sr.Recognizer(device_index=1) as source:
```

instead of,

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
```

Make sure you have installed `Pyaudio` with the command `pip install PyAudio` if you haven't.

Comment: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'device_index'.

Answer (score 0):

I think your microphone is not detecting. Try printing all the output devices and I am sure you will get a message saying no output devices found.

Comment: Oh, I'll look into it again and will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a project similar. You might want to try this.

```
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:

        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")
```